# como puedo hacer un div en .slim en ruby on rails?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, slim, recaptcha

Estoy maquetando un VIEW de ruby on rails en .slim

Este es un ejemplo de sintaxis:

```
  .row
    .col-xs-6
      .form-group
        .input-group
          input.form-control.input-lg id="card_cvv"  size="10" type="text" v-model='cc_ccv' placeholder="CVV"
            i.glyphicon.glyphicon-question-sign
```

La cosa es que necesito hacer un div pero no veo documentación de como hacer un div:

Como hago ese div?

necesito algo como:

```
.div class="g-recaptcha brochure__form__captcha" data-sitekey="llaveDelSitio"
```

Agradeceria su ayuda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cuando pones `.foo` en slim, le estás indicando que quieres un `div` con una class igual a `foo`, por ende `.foo` genera:

```html
<div class="foo"></div>
```

Si quieres crear una etiqueta html simplemente pones el nombre de la etiqueta:

```html
div algo
```

creará

```html
<div>algo</div>
```

Comment: Gracias :3 esa era la jugada <3